# iOS: jerkiness when animation stops and keeping animation in sync with modal

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am trying to perform a transform for the views on y axis using `CABasicAnimation`:

```
for(int x = 0; x < viewsArray.count; x++)
{
    CABasicAnimation *startAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
    [startAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_RADIANS(-55.0f)]];
    [startAnimation setDuration:5.0];
    startAnimation.delegate = self;
    UIView *view = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:x];
    [startAnimation setValue:@"rotate" forKey:@"id"];
    [view.layer addAnimation:startAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
}
```

Nothing fancy. I would like just to keep the modal and the animation in sync, so in 
`animationDidStop` I try to set the transform again using a for-loop:

```
if([[anim valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"rotate"])
{
    aTransform = CATransform3DRotate(aTransform, DEGREES_RADIANS(-55.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    for(int x = 0; x < viewsArray.count; x++)
    {
        UIView *view = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:x];
        view.layer.transform = aTransform;
    }
}
```

But I realized after the animation stops the animation would jerk to the angle set by the transform in `animationDidStop`.

Does any one know why and what would be the best way to do this without having to use `removedOnCompletion = NO;`? I would like to avoid using that and would like to keep the animation always in sync with the modal layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it at the same time as you add your animation, but you'll need to supply a `fromValue` to the animation to stop it updating the presentation layer immediately:

```
for(int x = 0; x < viewsArray.count; x++)
{
    UIView *view = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:x];
    NSString *keyPath = @"transform.rotation.y";
    NSNumber *toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_RADIANS(-55.0f)];

    CABasicAnimation *startAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
    [startAnimation setFromValue:[view.layer valueForKeyPath:keyPath]];
    //[startAnimation setToValue:toValue]; We don't need to set this as we're updating the current value on the layer instead.
    [startAnimation setDuration:5.0];
    [view.layer addAnimation:startAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
    [view.layer setValue:toValue forKeyPath:keyPath]; // Update the modal
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I will try it. But at the meanwhile, can you elaborate more on `setFromValue:[view.layer valueForKeyPath:keyPath]];`? and how is it able to stop updating the presentation layer?

Comment: Fair enough - I'm not not sure I phrased that particularly well. If you don't set the `fromValue`, it will animate from the current presentation value to the `toValue`. Therefore, updating the modal will then provide a `fromValue` of the updated value. Same thing happens with `toValue` so you don't actually need to bother setting that in this case - I'll update my answer to say that.

Comment: But for the first case in the loop, if there is not `toValue` it would not be animating at all.

Comment: It should still animate without a `toValue` as we're now also setting the layer's transform to the value we want to animate to. Have you tried it?

Comment: Commenting though phone; but I will. Thanks.

Comment: Des funzt. So, what this -`[view.layer valueForKeyPath:keyPath]` means is that we are using KVC to grab `keyPath` and with keyPath being `@"transform.rotation.y`.. How does that derive the `fromValue`? How does that know the point to animate from?

Comment: It didn't work? My intention was to set `fromValue` to whatever the current value was on the layer before the animation/update. Ignoring the KVC stuff, the basic idea was to grab the current transform from the layer, create an animation with the current transform as the `fromValue`, set the layer's transform to the new target value and add the animation to the layer. When the animation runs, it will use this new value set on the layer as its `toValue`.

Comment: It works that what I meant. One last thing: could the same way be applied to when using `[UIView animation....^{}];` to update the layer modal as well?

Comment: Oh, my bad! German? Also thought you may have voted or accepted my answer if it worked ;]. If I'm understanding you correctly with the `UIView` question, then this is kind of how things work by default - say you want animate the `frame` of a `UIView`, you set the `frame` in the animation block and that also becomes the view's new `frame`, you don't need to set it again in the completion block.

Comment: Stefan, then ending with -de, who would have thought that you were German? ;-) No, am not accepting your answer, but am doing it and giving you also an upvote instead. Many thanks for your explanations.